# File upload button is not clickable with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
data-ng-disabled="disableUpload"
```

How to work with such attribute?

I will elaborate more on this,

I want to upload a file by clicking on the + icon near add file button, but the below code says its disabled.

The code snippet is

[image]

I gave the xpath as below but nothing is working out .Please assist

```
@FindBy(xpath="//button[@id='createMoreButtonAs22'][@data-ng-disabled='disableUpload']")
```

or

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='createMoreButtonAs22']/i")
```

## function

```
public void addFiles() throws InterruptedException { 

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(addfilebtn));

    boolean flag = addfilebtn.isEnabled();
    if (flag) {

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", addfilebtn);

        System.out.println("After clicking");

    } else
        System.out.println("Element cannot be clickable");
}
```

}

but still not working. How to click the button so that file can be uploaded?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. If the button is disabled, you won't be able to click it. It will need to be enabled first. Are you asking how to enable it before clicking it? Or is it currently enabled and you want to disable it? There's not enough information. The current code snippet doesn't show "createMoreButtonAs22" or "data-ng-disabled="disableUpload", can you add the relevant code/DOM?

Comment: Thanks for the review. I have edited the post  for more clarification

Comment: Now its working  :) I gave the ID of the element and enabled it ..

Answer (score 1):

Try using just `//button[@id='createMoreButtonAs22']`.